# Quickblox login is not working using 3.3.1 sdk

Tags: java, android, session, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have integrated QuickBlox, everything is working fine, suddenly I am getting this error. I have tried to get why it is coming but didn't get any solution.

My code:

```
ChatHelper.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle bundle) {
                if(progressDialog!=null)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                loginToChat();
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "QB Chat Login successfully");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Error Login in Home Screen>>>" +e);
                if(progressDialog!=null)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });



private void loginToChat() {
        if(SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().getQbUser()!=null){
            final QBUser user = SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().getQbUser();
            ChatHelper.getInstance().loginToChat(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle bundle) {
                    android.util.Log.v(TAG, "Chat login onSuccess()");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

                    android.util.Log.w(TAG, "Chat login onError(): " + e);


                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Log cat:

```
 > D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
    >                                                            *** RESPONSE *** b4c54adf-b802-4327-b74b-96cc3fc5314d ***
    >                                                            STATUS : 201 
    >                                                            HEADERS
    >                                                                X-Runtime=0.012808
    >                                                                Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
    >                                                                QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
    >                                                                X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1
    >                                                                QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2017-06-07 13:56:00 UTC
    >                                                                Status=201 Created
    >                                                                X-Request-Id=4a8acb4c-6166-42c0-b85a-a038d61af56b
    >                                                                X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 201
    >                                                                Connection=Close
    >                                                                X-Android-Sent-Millis=1496836559559
    >                                                                Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
    >                                                                Date=Wed, 07 Jun 2017 11:56:00 GMT
    >                                                                X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
    >                                                                Server=openresty/1.9.15.1
    >                                                                ETag=W/"c74341ada523f27d4d495a2443d502a6"
    >                                                                Content-Length=239
    >                                                                Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000max-age=15768000;
    >                                                                X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
    >                                                                X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN
    >                                                                X-Android-Received-Millis=1496836559866
    >                                                                Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
    >                                                            BODY
    >                                                                '{"session":{"application_id":52126,"created_at":"2017-06-07T11:56:00Z","id":170143275,"nonce":-982948609,"token":"76c7ad273008bd4d1a3b87fd80551e046b00cb9e","ts":1496836558,"updated_at":"2017-06-07T11:56:00Z","user_id":0,"_id":"170143275"}}'
    > 06-07 17:25:59.937 4348-4348/com.talktotherapist D/AndroidRuntime:
    > Shutting down VM
    >                                                                    
    >                                                                    
    >                                                                    [ 06-07 17:25:59.937  2014: 4508 D/         ]
    >                                                                     x = 0.110770,  y = 0.138312,  z = 10.251881 06-07 17:25:59.958 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84 06-07 17:26:00.119
    > 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84 06-07 17:26:00.123
    > 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84 06-07 17:26:00.123
    > 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84 06-07 17:26:00.123
    > 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84 06-07 17:26:00.123
    > 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84 06-07 17:26:00.124
    > 4348-4451/com.talktotherapist D/SettingsInterface:  from settings
    > cache , name = android_id , value = 8dc776344146c84
    >                                                                       
    >                                                                       --------- beginning of crash 06-07 17:26:00.127 4348-4348/com.talktotherapist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    >                                                                    Process: com.talktotherapist, PID: 4348
    >                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
    > java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
    >                                                                        at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1197)
    >                                                                        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:527)
    >                                                                        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:829)
    >                                                                        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:314)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:88)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:40)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    >                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
    >                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
    >                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
    >                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
    >                                                                        at com.quickblox.auth.session.b.save(Unknown Source)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSessionManager.setActiveSession(Unknown
    > Source)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSessionJsonParser.extractEntity(Unknown
    > Source)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSessionJsonParser.extractEntity(Unknown
    > Source)
    >                                                                        at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBJsonParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.quickblox.auth.session.Query$VersionEntityCallback.completedWithResponse(Unknown
    > Source)
    >                                                                        at com.quickblox.auth.session.Query.completedWithResponse(Unknown
    > Source)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(Unknown
    > Source)
    >                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    >                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    >                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5736)
    >                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    >                                                                        at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:910)
    >                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771) 06-07
    > 17:26:00.152 4348-4455/com.talktotherapist D/OpenGLRenderer:
    > ~CanvasContext() 0x7f983cd000 06-07 17:26:00.154
    > 4348-4455/com.talktotherapist D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext()
    > 0x7f85c49000
```

Please guide me how to resolve login issues.

Comment: hello Ash, please create issue for QuickBlox git repository https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues and attach more logs with server request and response when you get this error, they will can help you faster

Comment: please try to upload your specific full code so others can help you properly.

Comment: @ValentynTereshchenko, I have created issue on github.com.
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/412

Answer (score 1):

Please try to follow this steps, it works for me perfectly!
Hope it will helpful to you!

First you need to sign in quickblox.

```
QBUser user = new QBUser("username", "password");
QBUsers.signIn(user).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e("LOGIN ", "myID =" + qbUser.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
        Log.e("LOGIN Error", "error..SIGN IN*****");
    }
});
```

then use that user object to create session and then login to chat service.

here's code:

```
final QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
final QBUser qbuser = new QBUser("username", "password");
QBAuth.createSession(qbuser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
        user.setId(qbSession.getUserId());
        chatService.login(qbuser, new QBEntityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I have updated logcat, please check error, I have tried your answer but its not working

Comment: hii @Ash can you please post code of loginToChat() method you're using..!

Comment: Hii @Rucha, I have updated question and add loginToChat()

Comment: @Ash In log cat user id catch my eye(user id: 0) so make sure about user id or check carefully you are missing something or what!! you're code seems perfect to me, i cant find any problem. you can try my code as well it works perfect. Happy to Help! :)

Comment: Hi @Rucha, have you integrated group chat ? if yes can you suggest me if chat window is not refreshing then which method I need to call

Comment: hii @Ash are you asking about refreshing window in group chat or single chat? btw no i didn't integrated group chat yet but i'm looking forward to it.

Comment: yes, Asking, I have integrated but facing refreshing issues

Comment: hii @Ash is this answer help you to solve your problem then plz accept it.. and have you solve your refreshing chat issue? do you need any help?

Comment: @RuchaBhatt Muwahhh!! Why is their documentation wrong?

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth what you mean?

Comment: The documentation on the website for th Android SDK has syntax errors. Your code is different than what they have presented on the site. Funny thing is your code helped me whereas the support couldn't get to my question until this AM

Answer (score 0):

I am using QuickBlox Version 3.9.1 and this works for me

> JAVA

```
final QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
        final QBUser qbuser = new QBUser("USER_EMAIL", "USER_PASSWORD");
        QBAuth.createSessionByEmail(qbuser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
                qbuser.setId(qbSession.getUserId());
                chatService.login(qbuser, new QBEntityCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {
                        Log.e(TAG, qbSession.getToken() + " , " + qbuser.getEmail());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });
```

> KOTLIN

```
val chatService = QBChatService.getInstance()
        val qbuser = QBUser("USER_EMAIL", "USER_PASSWORD")
        QBAuth.createSessionByEmail(qbuser).performAsync(object : QBEntityCallback<QBSession> {
            override fun onSuccess(qbSession: QBSession, bundle: Bundle) {
                qbuser.id = qbSession.userId
                chatService.login(qbuser, object : QBEntityCallback<Any> {
                    override fun onSuccess(obj: Any?, bundle: Bundle) {
                        Log.e(TAG, qbSession.token + " , " + qbuser.email)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: QBResponseException) {

                    }
                })
            }

            override fun onError(e: QBResponseException) {

            }
        })
```

**Another way is to check through session parameters :**

```
public void loginToChat(final QBUser user, final QBEntityCallback<Void> callback) {
        if (qbChatService.isLoggedIn()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ChatService Logged In" + qbChatService.isLoggedIn());
            callback.onSuccess(null, null);
```

**And then call this method from wherever in the code you want to login QBChatService:**

```
public void loginChat(int qbUserId) {
        // Initialise Chat service

        QBSessionParameters sessionParameters = QBSessionManager.getInstance().getSessionParameters();

        int user_id = qbUserId;
        String password = null;
        if (sessionParameters.getSocialProvider() != null && sessionParameters.getSocialProvider().equals(QBProvider.FACEBOOK)) {
            password = QBSessionManager.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.e(TAG, "Logged in QBUser -> " + user_id + " ->" + password);
        } else {
            password = sessionParameters.getUserPassword();
            Log.e(TAG, "Logged in QBUser -> " + sessionParameters.getUserEmail());
        }


        final QBUser qbUser = new QBUser();
        qbUser.setId(user_id);
        qbUser.setPassword(password);
        loginToChat(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ChatService Logged In" + qbChatService.isLoggedIn());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error -> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
            return;
        }

        qbChatService.login(user, callback);
    }
```

Comment: Using your code, if I set qbUser with a wrong password: createSession returns an Error "Unauthorized". If I set qbUser with the right password, createSession enters its onSuccess callback but chatService.login enters its onError with the Error: Authentication failed, check user's ID and password. 
I am using your exact same code and I am always getting this last error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @yalematta You need to check first whether your session is alive

Comment: @yalematta Updated my answer, check now, hope it helps!

Comment: I keep getting the same error even after checking QBSessionParameters: Authentication failed, check user's ID and password

Comment: @yalematta post your code snippet, i will try to check

Comment: Here are the 2 functions I am using: https://gist.github.com/yalematta/c188c537f421f5edca6c298ee54c89f9 Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194367/discussion-between-yalematta-and-aakash).